# Chronos setting environment variable leads to error

Tags: mesos, dcos, mesos-chronos

I tried this both on the chronos config and in my job definition:

```
    "environmentVariables": [
        {
            "name": "DOCKER_API_VERSION",
            "value": "$(docker version --format '{{.Server.Version}}')"
        }
    ],
```

It always fails with:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: 404 page not found.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

The reason I'm trying to set that variable is because I'm running docker in docker and the client docker API sometimes has a different version than the server docker version and it has to be started with the `DOCKER_API_VERSION` env set in order to work.

I'm suspecting it's because of the computed value being set instead of a string value.

In the logs I can see it runs as supposed and I don't know why it crashes to be honest:

`docker run ... -e DOCKER_API_VERSION=$(docker version --format '{{.Server.Version}}') ...`

Comment: Because the value is not evaluated as you can see in the logs …

Comment: Well...I was aware of that. When ran in the console the command gets evaluated. I was wondering if there's a way to do that with chronos as well.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more explicit: Chronos (and FWIW Marathon) do not evaluate the values of env variables. You can do that in the `command` field, there stuff is evaluated.

Comment: Unfortunately that's evaluated on the child docker and not the host running it - the child can't receive the API version of the host calling it. This way I'm unable to determine if there's an incompatibility between the server API and client API.